# HMAC Auth Approach in WebAPI / Web Applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth, hmac

I am recently working on a WebAPI project where I will be opening up some endpoints for other intranet web applications to select some of my data within my OracleDB tablespace. One of my top concerns now is securing the WebAPI against invalid calls to my API.

I am looking at the HMAC approach where I share unique keys with different authorized web apps that can call my API.

My question is,
Assuming I share Key A with WebApp A and Key B with WebApp B, can the developer of WebApp A use Key A with his another WebApp C to gain access to my API and make 'authorized' calls? The key shared to them is susceptible to abuse in other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, your keys could be used everywhere. In general, HMAC approach is designed to authenticate messages. In other words, when you are using HMAC, you are 100% sure, that the key owner (except scenario when key was compromised) has sent you a request. Nothing can stop key-owner from sharing this key. But, the main thing is, that from perspective of your "**host**"-API, all the requests signed with particular key should be considered as the same **client**, independently of are they physically the same application or not.